# How to save files from Heroku?

Tags: git, heroku

I have a python program running on Heroku, which is deployed from github repository. But the program uses .txt files to save data about usage/logs. Sometimes I update the code, but the problem is that after I commit changes to github and deploy the program once again, all the said .txt files are copied from github, so I lose all the important data.

I already tried using `heroku run bash -a appname` to access bash and use git to push to my github account, buy it yielded a bunch of errors.

I also tried to just temporarily use `cat filename.txt` to copy the contents, but I have noticed that files are not different at from ones that I have on github, moreover, any changes that I make like `git init` or `git remote add origin ...` are not saved after I exit the console.

The ideal solution would be some way to commit to github from heroku, but the way to at least see the changes would be much appreciated as well. Maybe someone knows the way to do so?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I would consider a different approach: being a Python app you could have an endpoint (Flask) to fetch the data out and save it (even incrementally). It is probably easier and you only need to have a client app (or manually with Postman) to invoke the endpoint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heroku Dynos use an [Ephemeral Filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem), this is a read/write filesystem which is only available for as long as the Dyno is running, as soon as a Dyno is restarted or stopped (which will happen at least every 24 hours), any changes that were written to the filesystem will be destroyed. When a new Dyno is started, the Dyno will have the same filesystem that was compiled when your application was built during deployment.

To permanently store files, you will need to use a mass storage system such as AWS S3. AWS has a great public API, and plugins for all major languages and Frameworks.

For log files, it's recommended that you log to STDOUT, as all output from an application is collated and can be drained to a logging addon (https://elements.heroku.com/addons/categories/logging).